# How to use php as a template engine without requiring third party libs

Tags: php, html

I am tasked with updating a website for some people and the webhost is pretty terrible and I'm not that familiar with Php, but what I am looking for is Php template engine that I can use standalone instead of having to roll my own. Does anyone have any suggestions? I have found a lot that require composer, but the webhost doesn't have composer.

Comment: The same way as composer you can download their source codes from vcs/download page and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can itself be used as a template engine in a pinch. Write templates in individual files like:

```
Hello, <?= htmlspecialchars($name) ?>!
```

They can be rendered with a simple function like:

```
function render_template($_path, $_vars=array()) {
    extract($_vars, EXTR_SKIP);
    ob_start();
    require($_path);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

In practice:

```
print render_template("templates/hello.php", array("name" => "world"));

-> Hello, world!
```

The `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` in `render_template()` may be omitted if you always want to render templates directly. (That is, if you will always want the output of a template to be printed, rather than returned as a string.)

Note that the use of underscores in the variable names `$_path` and `$_vars` is significant: it reduces the risk that they will conflict with variables used by the template itself.

Comment: Interesting way of doing this, very different to my current approach

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). It's simple, powerful, and very well written. Composer is not required, but it is the easiest way to install Twig.

You also don't need Composer to be installed in order to use it. Just download [composer.phar](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) and upload it to your webhost, then use it like this `php composer.phar install`.

Comment: I was reading about twig, but I didn't think I could get it setup on my web host, but i will try running the phar.